# Possible to console log a LESS variable during compile?

Tags: css, debugging, web, less

I'm doing some debugging of a very complex parent / child theme system with Bootstrap and LESS CSS.  I won't get into the details of that issue, except to say that I'm declaring custom colors and other variables in `variables.less` but the compiled CSS is not using these variables, **however**, I've verified that the file is actually being compiled and successfully included.

So, what I really need is to be able to somehow `console.log` the LESS variables (specifically at compile runtime), but despite the fact that LESS claims to support javascript inside of LESS files, that wasn't working.  Can anyone shed light on this / have experience with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but despite the fact that LESS claims to support javascript inside of LESS files, that wasn't working.

It is:

```
@var: value;

.test {
    width: ~`console.log("@{var}"), "@{var}"`;
}
```

Comment: Generally its a good idea to explain _why_ your code answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping your JavaScript in an immediately-invoked function expression. As long as you return a value that Less expects, anything else that happens in that function seems fair game:

```
@myColor: red;

.test {
  color: `(function(){console.log("@{myColor}"); return "@{myColor}";}())`
}
```

Comment: That also works for me:
```@debug: ~`console.log("[LESS] value of i = @{i}")`;```